# How to import 'ClusterInstance' from aws_rds (module 'aws_cdk.aws_rds' has no attribute 'ClusterInstance')

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, modulenotfounderror

Trying to run the docs from (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_rds/ClusterInstance.html), it says `ClusterInstance` is a part of `aws_rds`. When `cdk synth` gets to that line, it says it can't find that module though. The confusing part is other parts of `aws_rds` get imported just fine. Also `dir(aws_rds)` shows most of the modules, just not this one.

I'm trying to run:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_rds as rds,
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
)
from constructs import Construct

from cdk_utils.get_param import get_param

class AuroraDbStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc(
            self,
            "Aurora TEMP VPC",
            max_azs=2,
            subnet_configuration=[
                ec2.SubnetConfiguration(
                    subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
                    name="Aurora TEMP Private Subnet",
                ),
            ],
        )

        cluster = rds.DatabaseCluster(self, "Database",
            engine=rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.aurora_mysql(
                version=rds.AuroraMysqlEngineVersion.VER_3_01_0
            ),
            ## HERE: When trying to access `rds.ClusterInstance`
            writer=rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned("writer",
                publicly_accessible=False
            ),
            readers=[
                rds.ClusterInstance.serverless_v2("reader2")
            ],
            vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(
                subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED
            ),
            vpc=vpc
        )
```

Exact traceback:

```
Synthesizing test-aurora-db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cdk/AuroraDB/app.py", line 23, in <module>
    AuroraDbStack(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/cdk/AuroraDB/aurora_db/aurora_db_stack.py", line 34, in __init__
    writer=rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned("writer",
AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk.aws_rds' has no attribute 'ClusterInstance'
```

Versions:

`cdk --version`: 2.106.0 (build 0d1a333) (Was 2.105.0 yesterday, which is where the docs are at).

`python3 --version`: Python 3.9.16

`npm --version`: 10.1.0

`node --version`: v20.7.0

I expected ClusterInstance to be a module of aws_rds. Maybe it got renamed, and the docs need updating? The confusing part is so many other modules are working fine, so I don't think it's python path related...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer finally, the python package `aws-cdk-lib` was out of date. Bumping it `2.81.0` -> `2.99.1` allows me to use rds.ClusterInstance.